# How can I capture every single click on the microcontroller?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm currently testing a microcontroller (azure sphere) that captures clicks 1/20th of a second but there are clicks in between that are missed when clicking very fast. I want to capture the clicks at half the time. How can I improve this code to capture each and every click?

Here is part of the code.

```
const struct timespec sleepTime = { 0, 100000000};

    while (true) {

        GPIO_Value_Type value;
        GPIO_GetValue(button_A_fd, &value);
        Log_Debug(
            "Button value (%d)\n", value);

        // Processing the button.

        //Turns LED ON; Button not pressed down
        if (value == BUTTON_UNPRESSED) {
            last_button_state = BUTTON_UNPRESSED;
        }
        else {
            // if last button state is 1 then now it is being pressed
            if (last_button_state == BUTTON_UNPRESSED) {
                // Flip LEDs
                if (active_led == BLUE_LED) {
                    active_led = GREEN_LED;
                }
                else if (active_led == GREEN_LED) {
                    active_led = BLUE_LED;
                }

                last_button_state = BUTTON_PRESSED;
                // sets the pointer to the 0 bit of the file to write
                lseek(fd_storage, 0, SEEK_SET);
                write(fd_storage, &active_led, sizeof(active_led));
            }
        }
        //wouldn't it be more for loops to catch button states faster?

        // Blinking the active LED.
        // reading input only when pressed and turn off other led
        if (active_led == GREEN_LED) {
            GPIO_SetValue(blue_led_fd, GPIO_Value_High);
            GPIO_SetValue(green_led_fd, GPIO_Value_Low);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
            GPIO_SetValue(green_led_fd, GPIO_Value_High);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        }

        else if (active_led == BLUE_LED) {
            GPIO_SetValue(green_led_fd, GPIO_Value_High);
            GPIO_SetValue(blue_led_fd, GPIO_Value_Low);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
            GPIO_SetValue(blue_led_fd, GPIO_Value_High);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        }
    }
```

How can I make the button capture all clicks? Thank you.

Comment: You have several options: 1) configure a hardware interrupt which will trigger a function whenever the button is clicked, 2) configure a timer interrupt which will handle blinking separately so that your main loop can poll the status continuously, 3) create a state machine which will change the LED statuses inside the main loop so that you don't have to use `nanosleep`.

Comment: @Groo Thank you so much. I was inclined towards the second option but I will check these all out.

Comment: Do not spam the SO you asked this question 2 hours ago.

Comment: @P__J__ It told me to ask the question again but more clear. The last one was closed and never even got an answer so it literally helps no one once the page is found.

Comment: Edit the first question. If the community will find it worth reopening - it will be reopened. Asklng the same question again because the previous one was closed is a SPAM

Comment: @P__J__ I edited the first one can nothing changed so I clicked the link that said "ask a new question" and did with the new guidelines.

Comment: @ColorfulCodes you did not. You changed `improve efficiency` to `make the button capture all clicks`. Do you think that it changes thew quality of the question? If nothing changed - it means that the question did not improve its quality

Comment: BTW you asked this question 2 days ago as well.